# Ubuntu 23.10 - Dock not hoverable and not listed in settings

Tags: gnome, 23.10

I'm not sure when it happened, but the Dock no longer appears in Settings nor is it hoverable if I move the cursor to the bottom of the screen.

[image: screenshot of settings missing Ubuntu Desktop or Dock settings]

If I show all applications, the Dock appears and I can click on it to launch apps.

[image: dock screenshot]

I have checked if the extension is enabled, and it is not. However, enabling it does nothing:

```
➜ ~ gnome-extensions enable ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com  
➜ ~ gnome-extensions list --enabled
➜ ~ # nothing is listed
```

Tailing the logs, it says it was enabled successfully:

```
Mar 23 17:46:47 me dbus-daemon[15136]: [session uid=1000 pid=15136] Activating service name='org.gnome.Shell.Extensions' requested by ':1.150' (uid=1000 pid=24616 comm="gnome-extensions enable ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com" label="unconfined")
Mar 23 17:46:47 me dbus-daemon[15136]: [session uid=1000 pid=15136] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.Shell.Extensions'
```

### Troubleshooting Attempts

1. I have tried removing and installing `gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock` to no avail.

```
➜ ~ sudo apt purge gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock
➜ ~ sudo apt install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
```

2. I have tried creating a new User and seeing if it was a User-specific configuration, and that did not work.
3. I have tried launching the control center with the following:

```
➜ ~ XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=ubuntu:GNOME gnome-control-center
18:01:30.9573      cc-ubuntu-panel[28342]: WARNING: Extension ding@rastersoft.com is not available or invalid (state 99)
18:01:30.9575      cc-ubuntu-panel[28342]: WARNING: Extension ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com is not enabled (state 6)
18:01:30.9575      cc-ubuntu-panel[28342]: WARNING: Extension tiling-assistant@ubuntu.com is not available or invalid (state 99)
```

This does bring back the Ubuntu Desktop settings, but changing them has no effect. In the logs when it starts, it says the `ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com` extension is not enabled.

[image: Screenshot of Desktop back]

4. I have checked the Tweaks app, and there are no options for modifying the Dock. I do not (as far as I am aware) have any Tweaks installed.

Comment: Same issue here. Did you find a solution?

Comment: @HellaMad unfortunately no. Slowly building up the energy to just reinstall Ubuntu haha